# Creating a list of who hasn't checked in with Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

For my school, we are using QR codes to check students into various rooms around campus. The QR code logs their email address and the location where they checked in on a Google Sheet.

Using a list of all the email addresses, I have a formula in sheets that marks each student as "Checked In" or "Not Checked In" based on whether or not their email was found among the list of logged email addresses (from scanning the QR code). Hope that makes sense.

I'd like to create a formula that goes through and pulls out all the "Not Checked In" students and puts them in a single column with no whitespace in-between.

I have a simplified example of what I have done and what I am trying to do at the link below. What I want to achieve (on the sample sheet) is Will, Wesley, and Worf in cells `G2`, `G3`, and `G4`, respectively.

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VmbcLl5FfNvf0nRe3iNp1Qtu8k5WcLheJDjPJh-em2E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Please use the following formula

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select A where A is not null and B='Not Checked In'")
```

[image]

---

**As a side note** (suggestion)

For your `B` column you could use this single formula in cell `B2` (instead of manually adding one in every row) and have all bellow cells auto populated.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A,$D:$D)),"Not Checked In","Checked In"),""))
```

*(Just make sure you first delete all cells from `B3` till the end)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`LEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)
- [`MATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378)

Comment: Please also try the side note (suggestion) at the end of my answer.